# Getting a database error on a Rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm getting an error on a query in PostgreSQL in a rake task I'm trying to et up.

```
  posts = Post.where("status IS ? AND publish_on < ?", 'queued', Time.now)
```

Here's the error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'queued'"
    LINE 1: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE (status IS 'queued' AND...
                                                            ^
    : SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE (status IS 'queued' AND publish_on < '2012-04-29 23:44:06.423516')
```

At first I thought it was the quotes, but changing them didn't work. Now I think it's probaly how I'm contstructing the and clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IS` is only for comparing against `TRUE`, `FALSE`, or `NULL`. You probably want `=` instead:

```
posts = Post.where("status = ? AND publish_on < ?", 'queued', Time.now)
```